# How to check Local FileSystem in PHP

Tags: php

I want to check in PHP that whether folder present in the `C:\Program Files\multichain` drive whoever open my website I have tried by `file_exist` but its not working. Its seems `file_exist` check only local system. I have written function as :

```
function checkMultichainFileLocation(){
  if (!file_exists(C:\Program Files\multichain)) {
     return false;
   } else {
      return true;
   }
}
```

Is there anyway is it possible to check? Thanks in advance.

Comment: So you want to check client's drive?

Comment: Yes that what my requirement is

Comment: PHP is a server side language not a client base, You can only check the folders and files inside the server. No way to check the files and folders who are browsing your website.

Comment: @josdev Not even using JS???

Comment: There is codes in Javascript for this functions , but clients browser need to give permission to do this. Normally every browsers will not allow to check their local folders and files, due to security reasons.

Answer (score 2):

PHP, like other server scripting languages, does not know anything about the client computers except what is returned by the browser. This typically includes session information, cookies and user input (e.g., HTML forms, file uploads). However, there is no way for the server to access the client's local storage. That is a security constraint enforced by all modern browsers. The only way to access the client's local storage is using a browser plugin of some sort (a classic example is ActiveX controls) or Javascript (running on the client, and itself having limited access to local storage for security reasons).

Bottom line: **No way to check with a purely PHP solution.**

Comment: @NikitaAgrawal "Maybe". See [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/371875/local-file-access-with-javascript] Basically, it isn't easy and it isn't universal.